# scroll top not activating

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have this simple code

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();


if (scroll >= 200 ) {
alert("scroll");
jQuery('body').addClass('at__body_menu--scrolled');
} else {
jQuery('body').removeClass('at__body_menu--scrolled');
}
});
```

That works on all pages except on home. 
I have no errors in console, and already tried to set

> jQuery(document) 
>   and 
>   jQuery('body,html')

This is Wordpress theme I am working on my localhost, so not able to provide a link.
Is there any possible reason for this?
Thank you.

Comment: much better if you have link.. Alright, provide a screenshot instead on console and home page

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am not able to move it to some hosting right now. this is link to screenshots [link]http://imgur.com/a/a5GiW thank you